# Psycopg2 can not create table

Tags: python, database, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2

From Jupiter notebook, I was able to create Database with Psycopg2.
But somehow I was not able to create Table and store element in it.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

con = psycopg2.connect("user=postgres password='abc'");
con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT);

cursor          = con.cursor();
name_Database   = "socialmedia";

sqlCreateDatabase = "create database "+name_Database+";"

cursor.execute(sqlCreateDatabase);
```

With the above code, I can see database named "socialmedia" from psql (windows command prompt).

But with the below code, I can not see table named "test_table" from psql.

```
import psycopg2

# Open a DB session
dbSession = psycopg2.connect("dbname='socialmedia' user='postgres' password='abc'");
# Open a database cursor
dbCursor = dbSession.cursor();
# SQL statement to create a table
sqlCreateTable  = "CREATE TABLE test_table(id bigint, cityname varchar(128), latitude numeric, longitude numeric);";
# Execute CREATE TABLE command
dbCursor.execute(sqlCreateTable);
# Insert statements
sqlInsertRow1  = "INSERT INTO test_table values(1, 'New York City', 40.73, -73.93)";
sqlInsertRow2  = "INSERT INTO test_table values(2, 'San Francisco', 37.733, -122.446)";


# Insert statement
dbCursor.execute(sqlInsertRow1);
dbCursor.execute(sqlInsertRow2);

# Select statement
sqlSelect = "select * from test_table";
dbCursor.execute(sqlSelect);
rows = dbCursor.fetchall();

# Print rows
for row in rows:
    print(row);
```

I can get elements only from Jupyter notebook, but not from psql.
And it seems elements are stored temporarily.

How can I see table and elements from psql and keep the element permanently?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any `dbCursor.execute('commit')` in the second part of your question?

You have provided an example with AUTOCOMMIT which works, and you are asking why `results are stored temporarly` when you are not using AUTOCOMMIT?
Well, they are not commited!

They are stored only for the current session, that's why you can get it from your Jupyter session

Also:

- you don't need to put semicolons in your python code
- you don't need to put semicolons in your SQL code (except when you execute multiple statements, which is not the case here)

Comment: I got it.
I missed very important thing.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm in the midst of migrating from MySQL connections which autocommit so this sanity check was exactly what I needed.  It seems like every psycopg2 connection will require setting the isolation mode directly to whatever is expected instead of an implicit autocommit.