# POSTGRES: CREATE TABLE doesn't save

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql, heroku

I'm connecting to a postgres database in Heroku and trying to create a table. I run the code below but no new table shows up in the database.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
create_table = (""" CREATE TABLE test_table (account_address__c varchar); """)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(create_table)
conn.close()
```

Can you help?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Psycopg2 can not create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846961/psycopg2-can-not-create-table)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add

```
conn.commit()
```

.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(create_table)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```